How to recursively modify values of dicts inside dicts?
I'm trying to encrypt all the data inside the json, I need the program to encrypt the data if it's anything other than a dict, but recursively modify it in the dicts inside the json, here's an example:
// Original JSON
{
    "id": "00000000",
    "size": 5,
    "data": {
        "name": "example",
        "date": "00-00-0000"
    }
}

After the function:
{
    "id": "!(&$#*)@(DJ(UDIS)(@",
    "size": "()*#@EJD",
    "data": {
        "name": "(#*JR#(WD)*@DAS&HD$F",
        "date": "A*(&SDU(*AJSC"
    }
}

This is the code I've tried, but it isn't recursive.
async def insert_one(self, collection: str, json: dict):
    enc_json = {
        self.encryption.encrypt(key): self.encryption.encrypt(value)
        for key, value in json.items()
    }
    return await self.database["Disect"][collection].insert_one(enc_json)


Your "after the function" dict doesn't have encrypted keys, only encrypted values. But your code has self.encryption.encrypt(key). So should keys be encrypted or not?

yes, correct, but for the sake of the example and better understanding I typed it like that.

As per the linked duplicate - Loop through all nested dictionary values - Use isinstance to check for dicts and encrypt those in the value part. Also, your insert_one function involves database actions which have nothing to do with the encryption step, you should separate the two so that you actually have a recursive function you can use for encryption. Otherwise each recursive call would write/overwrite partial/junk data.

Also, should lists be lists of encrypted values or just encrypted text? If so, handle that in a similar way, with isinstance.
